# Filter out a facility in syslog-ng

Tags: linux, unix, logging, syslog-ng

Following are the some contents of my `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf`related to logging in to the file `debug.log`

> source s_sys {
>       file ("/proc/kmsg" log_prefix("kernel: "));
>       unix-stream ("/dev/log");
>       internal();
>       # udp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(514)); };
>
> destination d_mesg {
>   file("/tmp/log/debug.log"); };
>
> filter f_filter2   {
>   level(info..emerg) and
>                        not facility(mail,authpriv,cron); };
>
> log { source(s_sys);
>   filter(f_filter2);
>   destination(d_mesg); };

I would like to take your attention towards the line containing "filter". There you can see that i am filtering out the logs from `mail`, `authpriv` and `cron`. As far as my knowledge goes, `mail`, `authpriv` and `cron` are pre-defined facilities of syslog.

My query is :

I have a written a daemon named "pm" which also uses the syslog APIs for logging. Now whatever my daemon logs, goes into the file `/tmp/log/debug.log` as you can see above. I would like to filter out the logs of "pm" from going into `/tmp/log/debug.log`. To make it more clear i would like to have the filter like

filter f_filter2   { level(info..emerg) and
                     not facility(mail,authpriv,cron,pm); };

Please Note : the difference in f_filter2 compared to above.

Is it possible to do this ? How can i prevent `pm` logs from going into `/tmp/log/debug.log`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer.

We can create filters using the filter keyword:

`filter <filtername> { expression; };`

Where expression is a simple boolean expression. You can use "and", "or" and "not" to connect builtin functions. Functions can be one of:

- facility(list of comma seperated facility names)
- level(list of comma seperated priority nammes OR a range separated by "..")
- `program(regexp to match program name)`
- host(regexp to match program name)
- match(regexp to match program name)

So, if we want to add our own program, for example "pm", to the filter use it like this:

> filter f_filter2 { level(info..emerg)
>   and not facility(mail,authpriv,cron)
>   and program(pm); };

And if we want to filter out the log messages of "pm", use the filter like this :

> filter f_filter2 { level(info..emerg)
>   and not facility(mail,authpriv,cron)
>   and not program(pm); };